# Magento 2 auto create custom table from custom module

Tags: model, magento2, magento-2.0

I just upgraded from Magento 1.7. I successfully created module, controllers, helpers etc.

Today I tried to create a model with custom table. I want the table to be auto-created. I did following steps:

I created a module with following directory structure:

```
<Ashutosh>
  <Pandey>
      <etc>
          module.xml
      <Model>
      <Setup>
          InstallSchema.php
```

Here are the contents of each file:

**InstallSchema.php**

```
<?php

namespace Ashutosh\Pandey\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;

class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{
    public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();

        // Get table
        $tableName = $installer->getTable('ashutosh_friends');

        // Check if the table already exists
        if ($installer->getConnection()->isTableExists($tableName) != true) {
            // Create tutorial_simplenews table
            $table = $installer->getConnection()
                ->newTable($tableName)
                ->addColumn(
                    'id',
                    Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                    null,
                    [
                        'identity' => true,
                        'unsigned' => true,
                        'nullable' => false,
                        'primary' => true
                    ],
                    'ID'
                )
                ->addColumn(
                    'name',
                    Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                    null,
                    ['nullable' => false, 'default' => ''],
                    'Title'
                )
                ->addColumn(
                    'friend_type',
                    Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                    null,
                    ['nullable' => false, 'default' => ''],
                    'Summary'
                )
                ->addColumn(
                    'created_at',
                    Table::TYPE_DATETIME,
                    null,
                    ['nullable' => false],
                    'Created At'
                )
                ->addColumn(
                    'status',
                    Table::TYPE_SMALLINT,
                    null,
                    ['nullable' => false, 'default' => '0'],
                    'Status'
                )
                ->setComment('Ashutosh Friends Table')
                ->setOption('type', 'InnoDB')
                ->setOption('charset', 'utf8');
            $installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);
        }

        $installer->endSetup();
    }
}
```

**module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Ashutosh_Pandey" setup_version="1.0.0" active="true"/>
</config>
```

Then on command prompt from my magento2 directory, I executed the command:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

The command runs successfully but the table is not getting created.
I then also executed the command:

```
php bin/magento setup:db-schema:upgrade
```

but still nothing happen.

Note: I can read table successfully if I create it manually in database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Magento matches the module version specified in module.xml against entries in the database table setup_module. You could try to remove the entry of your custom module which should trigger magento to run the install script again when using php bin/magento setup:upgrade

```
select * from core_config_data;

delete from setup_module where module="<YOURMODULE>";
```

Comment: simply awesome dude.. +1 from me :-)

Answer (score 0):

Change

`if ($installer->getConnection()->isTableExists($tableName) != true) {`

to either

`if (!$installer->getConnection()->isTableExists($tableName)) {`

or

`if ($installer->getConnection()->isTableExists($tableName) !== true) {`

Very small difference. See http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: Hi Maddy, I did use above operators, but it looks like Magento2 is not picking my InstallScript.php.  I followed multiple examples like this: https://www.ashsmith.io/magento2/module-from-scratch-part-3-database-tables/

Comment: I intentionally put an erroneous statement and it looks like it is reading the InstallSchema file, but not creating the table. Also, I removed the if() statement and tried to create the table directly.

Comment: You can use xdebug to see why it is not creating a table. Thats how I tested it. and it works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use UpgradeSchema.php since the module was already installed.

Basically almost the same as InstallSchema.php but with the name of the function renamed to upgrade and the implementation of the class UpgradeSchemaInterface instead of InstallSchemaInterface

Then run `magento setup:upgrade` and it will work

This is a magento question which has been answered [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/86085/magento2-how-to-database-schema-upgrade)